# Should I ask a question that I know is a duplicate and then flag it myself?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I remember reading somewhere that Stack Exchange sites benefit from some amount of duplication to improve the surface area of searches. If I've thought of a way to phrase a question very differently from how it is currently phrased while having it mean the same thing, should I ask that duplicate question and then immediately flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: Did you post this one on purpose? ;)

Comment: Oh, the irony...